# Using flags in android so to start from the same activity from where the app was closed

Tags: android

I am creating an app in which the registration pages are 3 in number. When the user registers on the first page and saves it, it goes to the second page and so on. If suppose the user has only registered on the first page and has closed the app then when ever the user opens the app it should bring the user to the second page of registration. How to do this?

Comment: Save the activity class in your `sharedPreference` and check on next time when opening the app. Use if else to open the activity which is stored in `sharedPreference`

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your fist signup page contain email and password.
If firstpage signup is successful then set data of first page in `SharedPreferences` like below.

**AppTypeDetails is class for SharedPreferences.**

```
 AppTypeDetails.getInstance(SignUpActivity.this).setEmail(<Your Email ID>);
 AppTypeDetails.getInstance(SignUpActivity.this).setPassword(<Your Password>);
```

**AppTypeDetails.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class AppTypeDetails {

    private SharedPreferences sh;

    private AppTypeDetails() {

    }

    private AppTypeDetails(Context mContext) {
        sh = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
    }

    private static AppTypeDetails instance = null;

    /**
     * 
     * @param mContext
     * @return {@link AppTypeDetails}
     */
    public synchronized static AppTypeDetails getInstance(Context mContext) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new AppTypeDetails(mContext);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    // get username
    public String getEmail() {
        return sh.getString("email", "");
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        sh.edit().putString("email", email).commit();
    }

    // get password
    public String getPassword() {
        return sh.getString("password", "");
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        sh.edit().putString("password", password).commit();
    }

    public void clear() {
        sh.edit().clear().commit();
    }

}
```

Now close your app and open again

Now check below code in splash screen.

```
String email = AppTypeDetails.getInstance(SplashScreen.this).getEmail();
String pass = AppTypeDetails.getInstance(SplashScreen.this).getPassword();

if (email == null && pass == null) {

    // Open First SignUp page

} else {
    // Open Second SignUp page
}
```

And do continue.

If signup page 2 is successful then save data of 2nd page in `SharedPreferences` and check data of first page and second page in splash screen.
If data of first page and second page is not null then directly open 3rd page.

**For clear `SharedPreferences` :**

Call clear() method on logout.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have one start icon but want to show different activities depending on the current state 
(or shared preferences as suggested by @Chirag Savsani)
you can implement an invisible StartupActivity that decides which activity should be visible

```
public class StartupActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (!hasUserRegistered()) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, RegisterUserActivity.class));
        } else if (!hasUserLogedIn()) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginUserActivity.class));
        } else {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        }
        finish(); // else StartupActivity keeps open after started activity closes
    }
}
```

In the manifest.xml set this StartupActivity as the only "LAUNCHER" to make it appear in android program manager

```
<manifest ...>
    <application... >
        <activity android:name="StartupActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Can I use onSaveInstanceState to do this task? I have read about this onSaveInstanceState but not able to understand how to use it in this situation

Comment: @k3b: You said: "you can implement an invisible StartupActivity". Are you making the activity literally invisible? How is it? Is it by creating an activity without any layout? Please explain.

Comment: @priyamtheone: you are right. an actitvity without any loayout that does nothing more than starting the right Activity. the example `StartupActivity` has all the code necessary