# Checking condition before starting an activity

Tags: android

I want to check some condtiton before the main activity starts and based on test result i have to either start a new activity or continue the same activity. How to do this?

Comment: Check it in your `onCretee()` method before `setContentView`.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34037705/using-flags-in-android-so-to-start-from-the-same-activity-from-where-the-app-was/34038637#34038637

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check it in your OnCreate() method. It is called when your activity start.

```
onCreate(...){
....
if(want this){
//continue;
}else{
// start new activity
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default Activity to start is set in the manifest, so a better approach to your problem would be to use fragments. Keep in mind that fragments are faster/lighter, so instead of using Application as a "decision" class to start activities (bad practice), use your main activity. In your onCreate() method, check for your condition and attach the needed fragment.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  if(startNewActivity) {
    // TODO Fire off intent to start new activity
    finish(); // Closes the current activity
    return; 
  }
  // TODO Code for current activity.
}
```

`startNewActivity` is a boolean indicating whether to launch a new activity or not. It should be assigned a value depending on your condition.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am using java `annotation` to handle this case:

1. Create the [Annoation class](https://gist.github.com/leiweibo/8666469b5b22bc2cf90d)
2. Create [CustomContext.java](https://gist.github.com/leiweibo/e177b995d9d60abf54c2) with a `startActivity` method in it
3. Create the [Interceptor.java](https://gist.github.com/leiweibo/2dca899f4edb4d387635)
4. Create a class which implement Interceptor  [like this](https://gist.github.com/leiweibo/8fb5e3e67f6cd2101378) (named DemoInterceptor.java here)
5. Declare a static variable of DemoInterceptor in your activity. and the demo Activity should like [this](https://gist.github.com/leiweibo/1cc5d88b06abc3db8dd6)  then, start the activity via the custom startActivity in step #2

enjoy and let me know if you have any further question.